# plsql procedures while executing an error invalid identifier 00904

Tags: oracle, plsql

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq0UF.png)

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(DID INT,DNAME VARCHAR2(20),DLOC VARCHAR2(20));


INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(101,'SRINATH','HINDUPUR');
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(102,'SAINATH','ANANTAPUR');

create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_DEPARTMENT
             (P_DID IN DEPARTMENT.DID%TYPE,
                    P_DNAME IN DEPARTMENT.DNAME%TYPE,
                    P_DLOC IN DEPARTMENT.DLOC%TYPE,
                    P_ERROR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DID,DNAME,DLOC)VALUES(P_DID,P_DNAME,P_DLOC);
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        P_ERROR_MSG:=SQLERRM;
END ADD_DEPARTMENT;
```

iam writing a simple procedure try to excute but it shows object_id:invalid identifier how i can solve
[complete procedure execution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfplH.png)

Comment: can any one tell me how can i solve

Comment: tony andrews sir can you tell me the solution for this procedure

Comment: tony andrews sir can you send any real time  application for pl/sql and material pls

Comment: my mail id  is srsrinath378@gmail.com

Comment: Your posted procedure doesn't have any reference to `OBJECT_ID`. Clearly this is not the source which generated the error. If your DEPT1 table matches the projection of [the famous SCOTT.DEPT table](https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/the-emp-and-dept-tables-in-oracle/) then your code should compile.

Comment: can any one tell me how can i solve

Comment: Seriously, solve what???? Built that table, those inserts work. Built that procedure, it compiles and when run it inserts a record. So again, what is the problem?

Comment: it will come same error can be displayed i will post error message screen shot in the above

Answer (score 0):

One of your column names may be wrong in the parameter list/insert. Try just using varchar2 for all of them and see if that helps

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_DEPT2
                         (P_DEPTNO IN VARCHAR2,
                          P_DNAME IN VARCHAR2,
                          P_LOC IN VARCHAR2,
                          P_ERROR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DEPT1(DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC)VALUES(P_DEPTNO,P_DNAME,P_LOC);
  COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  P_ERROR_MSG :=SQLERRM;
  END ADD_DEPT2;
```

Comment: have a look at your insert statement so. Could be one of the column names is wrong

Comment: Actually removing the %TYPE seems like going in the wrong direction to me. With %TYPE in place, the code wouldn't even compile if those were not valid columns in the table. 

Are you getting a compile time or runtime error? It's static SQL, so it should be compile time. Can you show us the specific error information?

Answer (score 0):

> "it will come same error can be displayed"

No, no it won't. Let's prove it by running the code you posted.

Here is your table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(DID INT,DNAME VARCHAR2(20),DLOC VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(101,'SRINATH','HINDUPUR'); 

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES(102,'SAINATH','ANANTAPUR');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Here is your procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_DEPARTMENT
  2                      (P_DID IN DEPARTMENT.DID%TYPE,
  3                                     P_DNAME IN DEPARTMENT.DNAME%TYPE,
  4                                     P_DLOC IN DEPARTMENT.DLOC%TYPE,
  5                                     P_ERROR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2)
  6  IS
  7  BEGIN
  8     INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DID,DNAME,DLOC)VALUES(P_DID,P_DNAME,P_DLOC);
  9     COMMIT;
 10  EXCEPTION
 11     WHEN OTHERS THEN
 12     P_ERROR_MSG:=SQLERRM;
 13  END ADD_DEPARTMENT;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

And lo! not only does it compile but it runs without error too.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare                  
  2      v varchar2(128);
  3  begin
  4      add_department(666, 'Area 51', 'Roswell',  v);
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from department;

       DID DNAME                DLOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
       101 SRINATH              HINDUPUR
       102 SAINATH              ANANTAPUR
       666 Area 51              Roswell

SQL>
```

So once again I ask, what is the problem?

---

> "PLS-00905: object SCOTT.ADD_DEPARTMENT is invalid"

In SQL*Plus:

1. Connect as SCOTT
2. alter procedure add_department compile;
3. show errors

Or apply the equivalent sequence for whatever IDE you use to write your code.

Comment: PLS-00905: object SCOTT.ADD_DEPARTMENT is invalid

Comment: SQL> select * from department;

       DID DNAME                DLOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
       101 SRINATH              HINDUPUR
       102 SAINATH              ANANTAPUR

Comment: i can post screen shot in the above from now

Comment: i have to write a link name as complete procedure execution to see and tell what is the problem sir

Comment: If this answer helped you should upvote and/or accept it. Accepted answers improve StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.